# SQL Server setup Virtual or Physical

Tags: sql-server

We are in the process of setting up new DB server but need some help on whether we should go Virtual hosting route or physical one. Here is the background info:

Database: SQL Server 2016 with SSRS
It will be centrally hosted with around max 200 concurrent users, system will be accessed by users a crossed globe. In future number of concurrent users may rise to 300 users.

Infra team has assured me that they will be setting up dedicated DB server but they want to host virtual server on it cause it is more beneficial from DR point of view.
Development team prefer to have physical server because it makes life easy when things goes wrong and needs investigation

I hope you can either provide me some guidance on it or point me in right direction on this dilemma.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a "right" answer for this question.  Knowing maximum concurrent users is only a small part of the puzzle.  Database sizes, transaction counts, number of databases, etc, etc...  Plus you would need to know information about the hardware it'll be hosted on in either environment plus what the required DR / failover requirement would be.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve Matthews noted you omitted all kinds of crucial details about the app. But in real life the use of Virtual Machines for production apps is very, very widespread both using VMWARE products and HyperV (Microsoft products). While you may lose 3-10% performance vs running directly on a machine there are many, many advantages to running on a virtual machine (Admins can allocate more memory, CPU and other resources easily if they are needed and available).

Another increasing popular approach is to virtualize using Azure (i.e. the 'cloud.') Here too you can add all kinds of resources as your app's needs changes but of course you will be charged for it. When you go with AZURE there are certain parts of the product you cannot run - see this http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Why-you-should-think-twice-about-Windows-Azure-SQL-Database

You may also want to see this from Microsoft:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-general-limitations/

But much of the administration, including backup, can be done by Azure which makes it very attractive to many shops.

Good luck whichever way you go.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback chaps. Sorry I was not clear, what I am looking for is there any benefit in setting creating single VM instance over host and adding additional layer of complexity rather then hosting directly on physical one.

I agree with VM benefits and makes sense if host going to load multiple instances of VMs but in our case it's loading single VM? Thanks